# ItemsControl - different child based on property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

How can I change the child of an `ItemsControl` based on an property of the child?

At the moment I have this `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FooBar}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This `ItemsControl` is bound to a `ObservableCollection` called `FooBar`. 
Every object inside the `ObservableCollection` got the same properties. 3 of the 4 property are boundto the `ItemsControl`.
The foruth property is called `deletable` and it's of type `bool`.
Now I want to check this property. If `deletable == true`, I want to see an other `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            //...
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

How can I switch between two `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` - with are bound to `OberservableCollection` - based on a propery?

Comment: How can the forth property of a collection affect how this is rendered? If you have 2 objects in `FooBar`, and `FooBar[0]` says `false`, while `FooBar[1]` says `true`, then which template should it use?

Comment: @Jai I thought the object is loaded first and then rendered. So that I can look on the property `deletable` between these two processes and can choose on which template it should be rendered.

Comment: Is there much difference between the 2 different templates you want to show? I am assuming that `deletable` set to `true` would simply provide a delete button? If so then you could show/hide the delete button based on that property.

Comment: @Bijington yes thats nearly everything. I don't need a complete different structure of the template. But how can I do that?

Comment: I have added an answer to show how you can achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is show/hide the Delete button based on your deletable property.

Try something long these lines:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FooBar}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                <Button Content="X" Grid.Column="3" Command="{Binding YOURDELETECOMMAND}"
                        Visibility="{Binding Deletable, Converter={StaticConverter BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Note you will also need the following declaration in your Resources

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

**Alternative Delete command approach**

The above Command binding will expect the YOURDELETECOMMAND to be defined on your FooBar class, if you would prefer to handle the deletion higher up (I am going to assume MVVM here). As Jai stated in the comments this is a recommended way to do it as you can directly access your `ObservableCollection` and delete the item in question.

```
<Button Content="X" Grid.Column="3" Command="{Binding DataContext.YOURDELETECOMMAND, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type vw:YOURVIEW}}}"
                        Visibility="{Binding Deletable, Converter={StaticConverter BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Note you will need this declaration in the root of your Xaml.

```
xmlns:vw="NAMESPACE_OF_YOUR_VIEW"
```

Comment: Actually, the better way is to make the `Command` delete that entry directly from the `FooBar` collection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This will help me alot. Can I change the property `IsEnabled` of the textbox too?

Comment: @Jai Good point! I have updated the answer to include this option.

Comment: @MyNewName Yes all you need to do is add this to your `TextBox`: `IsEnabled="{Binding Deletable}"`